# How to get all values from array where the condition is executed?

Tags: javascript

I have array like this and I want get all values where for example description is equal to given and i know how get first array value where condition is executed but i dont know how to get from all where description is equal to given.

```
 [
  Discovery {
    name: 'Lorem ipsum',
    description: 'lorem ipsum',
    date: 2019-12-15T22:03:17.078Z,
    url: 'https://loremipsum.io/',
    discoveryId: 1,
    userId: 1
  },
  Discovery {
    name: 'Lorem ipsum2',
    description: 'bbbbbbb',
    date: 2019-12-15T22:03:17.079Z,
    url: 'https://loremipsum.io/',
    discoveryId: 2,
    userId: 2
  },
  Discovery {
    name: 'Lorem ipsum3',
    description: 'bbbbbbb',
    date: 2019-12-15T22:03:17.079Z,
    url: 'https://loremipsum.io/',
    discoveryId: 3,
    userId: 3
  }
]
```

This is where the array comes from

```
let nextId;
const discoveryList = [];
class Discovery{
    constructor(name, description, date, url, discoveryId, userId){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.date = date;
        this.url = url;
        this.discoveryId = discoveryId;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    static addDiscovery(discovery, userId){
        discovery.discoveryId = nextId++;
        discovery.userId = userId;
        discoveryList.push(discovery);

        return discovery;
    }

static discoveryList(){
        return discoveryList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array based on your condition.  For example:

```
let filteredList = discoveryList.filter(d => d.description === "some value");
```